# Simulator shows black screen on second time run

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6.1

I'm using Xcode 6.1, on first time launch iOS 8 simulator is always fine. But if I quit it, and tried to open it again, I'll get a black screen.

I've tried reset content and settings button, but it is not helping. If I reboot my laptop, it will be fine. But still if it shows black screen on second time.

Can anyone please give me some suggestion here? There must be something I could do to reset the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it can take a while to boot the simulated device.  You can check on the progress by looking at the simulated device's syslog:

```
tail -F ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<Device UDID>/system.log
```

You can determine the UDID by running `xcrun simctl list`

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, this is indeed very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Select project-> go to general-> add launchscreen.xib in app icons and launch screen file